# Koopman composition operator theoretical approach to Ergodic Dynamical Systems

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, data-analysis

Given a dynamical system $T:X\to X$, the Koopman  operator $U$ is defined on the space of (complex-valued) functions on $X$. So for $f:X\to\mathbb C$, the action of the composition on the function $f$ reads:  $U(f):=f\circ T$.
Then, since $U$ is then a linear operator in a vector space, one is interested in the eigenfunctions especially those with eigenvalue 1.

But for *ergodic* transformations $T$, it is a fact that the only $T$-invariant function (i.e. $f\circ T=f$) is an a.e. constant  (almost everywhere, up to a zero-measure subset).

So what is the application of this transition to "observable space" for ergodic systems, if there is any? Actually I think, ergodicity is a property mostly assumed for real physical systems, and here the opposite is required?

References:
[Koopman Operator Spectrum and Data Analysis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313891298_Koopman_Operator_Spectrum_and_Data_Analysis),
[Igor Mezic: "Koopman Operator Theory for Dynamical Systems, Control and Data Analytics"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGF6NvQJ3HM),
[Introduction to Koopman operator theory ofdynamical systems](https://www.mit.edu/%7Earbabi/research/KoopmanIntro.pdf),
[Data-driven spectral decomposition and forecasting of ergodic dynamical systems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.acha.2017.09.001)

Comment: One application is the classical proof of the mean ergodic theorem, by means of the spectral theorem for unitary operators: see Tao's [blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/01/30/254a-lecture-8-the-mean-ergodic-theorem/)

Comment: "So what is the application of this transition to "observable space" for ergodic systems, if there is any?" Most obviously, there is none, for the reasons in your own message. "Actually I think, ergodicity is a property mostly assumed for real physical systems, and here the opposite is required?" This question of yours makes no sense, you need to have a look at spectral ergodic theory, but it would be difficult to detail much more here.